# Given a $17^\circ$ angle, construct a $1^\circ$ angle using only a compass and straightedge

Tags: geometry

> Given a $17^\circ$ angle, construct a $1^\circ$ angle using only a compass and straightedge

I've tried creating 20 seventeen angles so that there is a $360-20*17=20$ angle left. However, this is not possible as an angle can only be divided into powers of 2.

If we construct 64 seventeen degree angles, we are left an 8-degree angle. This can be bisected three times to achieve a 1-degree angle. Is this an valid construction?

Comment: Yes, this is a valid construction. Why did you fear it might not be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $17 \times 7 = 119$. Can you construct a $120$-degree angle?

Answer (score 2):

Construct a 60° angle and bisect twice.  Subtract the result (15°) from the given 17° angle and bisect.

Answer (score 1):

An further possibility would be to construct a regular pentagon by usual means. Subdivide it to obtain a decagon and once more for a icosagon. That one then amounts to a centry-angle of 18 degrees. Subtract your 17 degrees angle therefrom, and you are left with ...?

--- rk

Comment: If you use Ptolemy's method you have a 72° angle and also an overlapping 90° angle at the center.  There is already an 18° angle available by difference, so you do not have to subdivide the pentagon.